# Understanding the python code snippet

Tags: python, code-snippets

Please help me understand the following code snippet :-

```
def any(l):
"whether any number is known from list l"
    s = set(list(l)[0])
    for x in l:
        s.intersection_update(set(x))
    return len(s) > 0
```

Here l is a *list* containing the list of 3-tuples e.g [(17,14,13),(19,17,2),(22,11,7),(22,13,1),(23,10,5),(23,11,2),(25,5,2)] etc.
In particular I am facing difficulty understanding the line 3

```
s=set(list(l)[0])
```

Comment: It seems like this function is used to check how many common members of all the tuples in list l.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set(list(l)[0])
```

`list(l)` creates a new list from `l`and then `[0]` is to fetch its first item, which is `(17,14,13)`.
and then `set((17,14,13))` returns a set of this tuple.
set is a data structure which contains only unique hash-able elements.
    i.e `set((10,12,10))` equals `{10,12}`

```
>>> l=[(17,14,13),(19,17,2),(22,11,7),(22,13,1),(23,10,5),(23,11,2),(25,5,2)]
>>> list(l)[0]
(17, 14, 13)
>>> set(list(l)[0])
{17, 13, 14}
```

Answer (score 2):

In `s=set(list(l)[0])`, you're creating a set from the first element of the list. In your case, you could have used `set(l[0])` and it would do the same thing. Essentially, you're creating a set based on the first tuple of the list. Overall, your function is trying to find if there is any common element(number) between all tuples.

Answer (score 0):

A `set` is a python collection of hashable-types that has the special feature that no entity in the collection can repeat (the hash returned from it's `__hash__` magic method, and thereby also the boolean return from the `__eq__` method cannot be equal to any other entity in the list)  It is used wherever a collection is required that can not have repeated entities.

It's hard to tell the intention of the snippet entirely without knowing the context of its use, especially since the values you have for l are all tuples within a container list.  The `intersection_update` is a method of a set that returns a set from the original keeping only elements also found in the one that is passed as an argument.  The zero-indexed key is fetching the first tuple from the list.

http://docs.python.org/library/sets.html